# Getting 'Error occurred prerendering page' in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am facing during the deployment phase a prerender error which I am unable to understand:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/about". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
```

It would be great if you can tell me how to fix it and why is the error occurring in the first place.

Here is my layout code:

```
import { Inter, Roboto } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import Provider from "./Provider";
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import SeachBox from '@/components/SearchBox'
import SearchBox from "@/components/SearchBox";


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const roboto = Roboto({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "700"],
});
// this makes the website seo firendly
export const metadata = {
  title: "IMDB my first next app",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body className={roboto.className}>
        <Provider>
          <Header />
          <NavBar />
        <SearchBox />
        {children}
        </Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

My about page:

```
//chnage fonts later
import Link from "next/link";
import { PROJECT_GITHUB_LINK } from "../../../public/url";
import { GITHUB_URL } from "../../../public/url";
function About() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto space-y-4">
        <div className="bg-amber-300 dark:bg-amber-500 mt-3 pt-2 pb-2  sm:rounded-none ">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-left sm:text-3xl dark:text-white dark:font-semibold p-2">
            {" "}
            About this project
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="pt-5">
          {/* /** will add image later */}
          <div className="px-5 mt-5">
            <p className="text-lg text-left sm:text-xl">
              This is a simple project to demonstrate the usage of Next.js,
              Tailwind CSS, and next-themes. The project is a simple IMDb clone
              with a dark mode themeAbout this project This is a simple project
              to demonstrate the usage of Next.js, Tailwind CSS, and
              next-themes. The project is a simple IMDb clone with a dark mode
              theme switcher. The project is open-source and available on
              GitHub. The project was created by switcher. The project is
              open-source and available on
              {
                <Link
                  href={PROJECT_GITHUB_LINK}
                  className="hover:text-amber-600"
                >
                  {" "}
                  GitHub (click here)
                </Link>
              }{" "}
            </p>

            <p className="text-lg dark:text-gray-100 pt-2 sm:text-xl">
              The project was created by{" "}
              <Link href={GITHUB_URL} className="hover:text-amber-500">
                Venusai
              </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default About;
```

I even tried using suspense, but I don't think I did it correctly. Can you fix it and tell me how to do it?

My project repo: https://github.com/Venu005/imdb_clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `useSearchParams` in `NavBarItem`. So as the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout) says, you need to wrap it in a `Suspense`, because:

> Reading search parameters through useSearchParams() without a Suspense boundary will opt the entire page into client-side rendering. This could cause your page to be blank until the client-side JavaScript has loaded

> Ensure that calls to `useSearchParams()` are wrapped in a `Suspense` boundary.

> This will ensure the page does not de-opt to client-side rendering.

So in your `layout.js`, wrap `NavBar` within `Suspense`. Like so:

```
<Suspense>
  <NavBar />
</Suspense>
```

And don't forget to import `Suspense` at the top:

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
```

Comment: Thanks!!I don't know how I missed it